# How to Make Blocks wait in Simulink?

Tags: simulink, scheduling

I have two Blocks. Block A and Block B. Block A has a sampling time of 1 ms and Block B we do not know. It takes longer for Block B to do computing. I need to run A and then make it wait to run B. Until B is done with computing, A should not be run again. So every time A should run once and wait for B. How can I implement this on Simulink?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could use an enabled sub-system to have Block A run once the calculation of Block B is complete. If you use the display sample time options, can you not see what the sample time of block B is?

Comment: Probably yes, you can see it but we know that it takes longer for B to do the computing.

The problem with enabling, how can I generate enabling automatically after the block is done with computing?

Comment: @Farid1988 Make one of the outputs of the calculation a Boolean value the is set when the calculation is complete